# Xamarin: Error de excepción no controlado

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto, primero generé una carpeta llamada Notificaciones de ahí generé dos archivos que sería el login (principal) y el segundo sería Page2 (en donde quiero que se redireccione por medio de una API) pero me marca el siguiente error de excepción no controlado

> An unhandled exception ocurred

CÓDIGO

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;


[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]

namespace ProyectoNoveno.Notificaciones
{

    public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        public Login ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            enterButton.Clicked += enterButton_Clicked;
        }
        private async void enterButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEntry.Text))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe de Ingresar un Usario", "Aceptar");
                userEntry.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordEntry.Text))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe de Ingresar una Contraseña", "Aceptar");
                passwordEntry.Focus();
                return;
            }



            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
            enterButton.IsEnabled = false;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/API/api/usuario");
            string url = string.Format("/API/api/usuario/{0}/{1}", userEntry.Text, passwordEntry.Text);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            enterButton.IsEnabled = true;
            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) || result == "null")
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Usuario o Contraseña no valido", "Aceptar");
                passwordEntry.Text = string.Empty;
                passwordEntry.Focus();
                return;
            }


            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Notificaciones.Page2());
        }
    }
}

APP

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;



namespace ProyectoNoveno
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();       
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Notificaciones.Login());

        }
```

ESTO LO MAS RECIENTE LO QUE HE LOGRADO POR AHORA[image: Error 2]

[image: COmo puedo mejorar El try catch, soy nuevo en el desarrollo en xamarin]

Comment: En Java no te permite hacer el new HttpClient() ya que es abstracta (aunque por el error que te da no es eso). Te falta un try catch, depura línea a línea para ver donde y ponerlo.

Comment: Lo primero es que controle la excepcion para determinar que es lo que esta pasando realmente con la peticion

Comment: Mmmm... es lo que he puesto yo

Comment: Podrias darme tu opinion sobre el try catch y del error? gracias

Answer (score 1):

Podés probar esto:

En el método `OnCreate` del archivo `MainActivity.cs` del proyecto `.Droid` agregá estas líneas antes del `LoadApplication`:

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += ErrorHandler.CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
 TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += ErrorHandler.TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;
```

y después crea una clase llamada `ErrorHandler.cs` con el siguiente contenido:

```
public static class ErrorHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Tasks the scheduler on unobserved task exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="unobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs">
    ///     The <see cref="UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs" /> instance containing
    ///     the event data.
    /// </param>
    public static void TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs unobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs)
    {
        var newExc = new Exception("TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException", unobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs.Exception);
        LogUnhandledException(newExc);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Currents the domain on unhandled exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="unhandledExceptionEventArgs">
    ///     The <see cref="UnhandledExceptionEventArgs" /> instance containing the event
    ///     data.
    /// </param>
    public static void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs unhandledExceptionEventArgs)
    {
        var newExc = new Exception("CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException", unhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject as Exception);
        LogUnhandledException(newExc);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Logs the unhandled exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exception">The exception.</param>
    internal static void LogUnhandledException(Exception exception)
    {
        try
        {
            string error =
                $"Exception Caught:{DateTime.Now:F} The Error Message IS {exception.Message}\n\r full stack trace is {exception} ";
#if DEBUG
            const string errorFileName = "errorlog.txt";
            var libraryPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var errorFilePath = Path.Combine(libraryPath, errorFileName);
            File.WriteAllText(errorFilePath, error);
            Log.Error("Crash Report error not handled", exception.ToString());
#else
                // Log to Android Device Logging.
                Android.Util.Log.Error("Crash Report", error);
#endif
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Crash Report error not handled", ex.ToString());
            // just suppress any error logging exceptions
        }
    }
}
```

Puedes poner un breakpoint en cada uno de los métodos: `TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException` y `CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException` para ver mas detalles acerca de las excepciones que estas teniendo.

Comment: Me sigue dando este error (an error ocurred while sending the request )

Comment: Hola Daniel, pero entonces si estabas recibiendo el error dentro del `Try-Catch`... te fijaste que dice el `InnerException` ?

Comment: ya pude resolver el error, era la url, la API solo recibia un parametro que era la ID y por eso me salia el error, solo tuve que corregir la API